# Is possible to post a Facebook's profile wall into a Flash site?

Tags: flash, facebook, actionscript, facebook-wall

Someone have already done this?

I have a solution in mind, but I don't tried yet. Before trying i'm wanna know if it's possible.

My solution is just posting a wall into an html page and getting the source of page in Flash and parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the wall is a public wall (like a 'Fan' page), you can do a normal Graph API call and get the wall data -- e.g., https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed (more information about the data [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api)). Then you parse it with a JSON decoder and it has everything you need. You don't need any third-party Facebook API, not to register an application.

If it's a person's wall and it's not public, you need the user to connect to Facebook using Facebook Connect and/or OAuth. That gives you back an 'access token' that identifies the user's session, and you use that to make the requests. You need to register an application for that. You may also need additional permissions requested during login, depending on what you're doing. So it's a bit more complicated. More about that [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Live Stream API, you just have to sign in for an application id
Haven't tested it, so can't tell you how to implement this
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/